# How to prevent access to Admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building an Admin namespace and would like to know if there is a solution to prevent access to all controllers within this namespace to logged-in admins only.

The only solution I have found so far is adding the following to every controller:

```
before_action :require_admin

def require_admin
  unless current_user.admin?
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I am looking for something more global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use inheritance:

- Create an `AdminController`.
- Make it extend `ApplicationController`.
- Make your admin controllers extend `AdminController`.
- Put the filter and method in `AdminController`.
- Delete the filter and method from your concrete admin controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add that code to `ApplicationContoller` instead of adding it to every controller and use `skip_before_action :require_admin` in controllers that don't need admin privileges.

Comment: Best when most controllers do need admin privileges, of course. Normally I'd complain about Refused Bequest, but when it comes to security it's better to whitelist than blacklist.